# Html5 templates for website

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

We want to re-build our web site of our company which is important company in the country.

We are researching for free or premium html5 templates.We are looking for templates which is easy to edit and easy to add/update contents.

If the template has user console or something like that to add/update contents it will be really great.

We are not sure to rebuild our web site on our own.If we can find templates or something like that which includes specialities we want I think we can handle it.We need really professional designs in business area.

Any advice ?

Comment: try and google it, what cms are you using? I think the better way is to google

Answer (score 0):

You can use wordpress CMS with premium themes, as wordpress backend is easy to use and do add, edit, update and delete content. You can purchase a wordpress theme from [Themeforest](https://themeforest.net/category/wordpress/corporate), that will help you a lot to set up easily and meet your expectation. It do provide a demo content also, that can be set up in one click(using the instructions provided in purchased theme)